# add the same control several times on different parents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, controls

I'm trying to add a panel on two different panels in this way:

`_formMain.panel3.Controls.Add(_formMain.panel1);
 _formMain.panel4.Controls.Add(_formMain.panel1);`

What I obtain is that panel1 is added only to panel4 and it is removed from panel3.
It seems that the latest "Add" overwrites the others "Add". Is it true?
Why? How can I add the same panel to some differents controls?
Thank you

Comment: A control can have only one Parent.  Your second call automatically removes it from the panel3.Controls collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title says it all:

There **is** only one control and it can only be in **one** place, read it can only have one parent.

Therefore, if you change the `Parent` or `Add` it to another Control's `Controls` collection, which is ecxactly the same thing, it will disappear from the previous place.. So while `Add` doesn't sound like it, it amounts to a `Move`.

If you need **more** controls you need to **create** more controls! And of course they will be **different** Controls, with different properties and contents..

You can have more than one control show the same content if you keep them synch'ed. One prime example with automatic synchronizing would be two `DataGridviews`, both with the same `DataSource`. For other content, like Text or Images the syn'ching is up to you!

You may think about writing a clone function, that can create a deep copy but you will still have to do the syn'ing. This may be codeable as well, depending on the details.. Or you could make it into a UserControl and add fresh instances of it.